# Retrieving data from firebase in android in sorting order

Tags: android, firebase

first of all the code is work fine for me . data is retrieving from firebase finely i want see the last inserted data in top . but it's working reverse mode.  here is code for retrieving .

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.sonalirod.alwayswhite.Model.ADeposit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class admininterface extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button adminlogin, sh,retu;
    List<ADeposit> abc;


    DatabaseReference databaseBazars;
    public ListView deposit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admininterface);


        databaseBazars= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Deposit");
        adminlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adminlogin);
        sh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adminshow);
        deposit = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_deposit);
        retu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.returnbuttonn);
        abc = new ArrayList<>();


        deposit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        retu.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        adminlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ALogin.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        sh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                sh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                adminlogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                deposit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                retu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        });

        retu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                adminlogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                retu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                deposit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

}


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseBazars.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                abc.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ADeposit ks = ds.getValue(ADeposit.class);
                    abc.add(ks);
                }
                DepositList adapter = new DepositList(admininterface.this, abc);
                deposit.setAdapter(adapter);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

and the output is like this image [image]

in there the group inserted on database very last. but it's comes bottom of all datas. but i want the last inserted data top of all. and it would be great pleasure for me if you also tell me how to sort that data via date(like november ,december ) .

it's not duplicate . please take a look on my code .  i want here two sorting event one is descending (latest would be on top) and another is month wise sorting .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting Data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885657/sorting-data-in-firebase)

Comment: no . it's not solving my problem :/

Comment: "not solving" because...?

Comment: the solution is not specific . i actually don't get the answer .

Comment: You not understanding the solution doesn't mean that question is not the same as I've linked or that the answer to it doesn't solve your problem. What specifically are you having troubles with understanding?

Comment: on there they created a abstract class . how should i link that ? to my retrieving data process. and how can i sort the month wise data? could you be more specific to my question ?

Comment: it's just a simple solution. buddy . i got it . 


       just add this one line  Collections.reverse(abc); in Arrayadapter class.

Comment: yes, that is one way to do it. Or, if your view is paged, you can always add to start of the list.